# How to implement REST in my Web Application. I want to make a rest API for my website?

Tags: java, spring, rest, restful-authentication

I am working on an enterprise application and need to provide services to mobile app using REST.

I want to implement or build a REST API for my website using which I can build client side application as well as provide services to the mobile app for my website.

I have very less idea about it and for technical specification.

My website uses Spring Framework and is build upon Java.

Kindly guide me through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find some resources here about developing REST applications with Spring MVC

- http://blog.springsource.com/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/
- http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch18s02.html
- http://www.oudmaijer.com/2010/01/16/spring-3-0-rest-services-with-spring-mvc/

and a general tutorial about REST:

- https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/